# Filling slots using a group of three, with limited repetitions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Suppose we have 7 slots to fill with the letters A, B and C. We can pick A two times, B three times and C two times. How many combinations can be made?

My thought was to group A with C, to essentially find how to fill 4 out of the 7 slots, so we get $C_4(7) = {7 \choose 4} = 35$ and call it a day, but it can't be that easy.

What am i missing?

Comment: "How many *combinations*" "We have 7 *slots*"  Clarify what sort of objects you are wanting to count.  Give us an example of a few of the objects you are trying to count.  You say we can pick $A$ up to $2$ times and so on... but if we were to be using all seven of the slots, wouldn't that require that we used *exactly* two $A$'s three $B$'s and so on (*noting that $2+3+2=7$*)?

Comment: Think back to the concept of _arrangements with repetitions_.

Comment: In an extreme interpretation of what you were saying, for all I know we might be including _ _ A _ A_ C in our count

Comment: We want to calculate all the possible combinations the letters ABC can fill these 7 slots, but they can appear limited times. For example, this combination: AAAAAAA, cannot happen.

Comment: And so that brings me back to my question, you use the phrase "*up to*" but why bother including this phrase when $2+3+2=7$ and we have $7$ slots.  Why not phrase it "We can pick $A$ **exactly** two times, ..."?

Comment: Okay, I edited it.

Comment: In any case, the number of strings of $A$'s, $B$'s, and $C$'s of length $n$ with $a$ copies of $A$, $b$ copies of $B$, etc... with $a+b+c=n$ will be the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) $\binom{n}{a,b,c}=\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}$.  You could arrive at this yourself by starting as you had by picking which slots are used by $A$ or $C$ letting $B$ take the unpicked slots, then picking which of the picked slots was used by $A$ letting $C$ take the remaining for a total of $\binom{7}{4}\binom{4}{2}$ (*or by doing in a different order*)

Comment: The "what am I missing" was that you still needed to determine how $A$ and $C$ share those spaces that you set aside for them.  The problem becomes much more complicated if you have more letters available than you have spaces to fit them in.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very clear response. Cheers!